# What will this regular expression detect?

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring, markdown

I'm not the greatest expert in Regex strings, so I'm lost on what this one is supposed to find here:

```
@"\\[(.*?)\\]\\((\\S+)(\\s+(\"|\')(.*?)(\"|\'))?\\)"
```

I'm trying to get a markdown pattern going for an app. Can anyone help me with what sets of patterns this is supposed to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex seems to match Markdown formatting for hyperlinks. Particularly, those that specify the link directly and does not use the reference style.

```
[linked text](http://www.example.com/hyperlink "optional tooltip")
```

Capturing group 1 contains the linked text.
Capturing group 2 contains the hyperlink.
Capturing group 4 contains the optional tooltip.

Below are example hyperlinks to this question, one with and the other without tooltip:

- [What will this regular expression detect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285433/what-will-this-regular-expression-detect) (try hovering your mouse over this one)
- [What will this regular expression detect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285433/what-will-this-regular-expression-detect)

The source of the 2 hyperlinks above:

```
- [What will this regular expression detect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285433/what-will-this-regular-expression-detect "What will this regular expression detect?") (try hovering your mouse over this one)
- [What will this regular expression detect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285433/what-will-this-regular-expression-detect)
```

You can try matching the example text above with your regular expression. It will become clear once you see the result. This is a [demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dQ8mI0/1).

(I wrote `\[(.*?)\]\((\S+)(\s+("|')(.*?)("|'))?\)` in the demo above, since it is what is seen by the regex engine)

Answer (score 0):

```
\\[(.*?)\\]\\((\\S+)(\\s+(\"|\')(.*?)(\"|\'))?\\)
```

See ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

When \ characters are needed to escape Regular Expression Operators they must themselves be escaped in the string.

```
\\[      matchs [
(        starts capture group 1
   .*?      matches anything 0 or more times as few times as possible.
)        ends capture group 1
\\]      matches ]
\\(      matches (
(        starts capture group 2
   \\S+     matches all non-space characters
)        ends capture group 2
(        starts capture group 3
   \\s+     matches one or more space characters
   (        starts capture group 4
      \"|\'    matches a " or '
   )        ends capture group 4
   (        starts capture group 5
      .*?      matches anything 0 or more times as few times as possible
   ))       ends capture group 5
   (        starts capture group 6
      \"|\'    matches a " or '
   )        ends capture group 6
)?       ends capture group 3 of zero or one matches
\\)      matches )
```